# How to get format of SOAP parameters via PowerShell

Tags: web-services, wcf, powershell, soap

I'm trying to consume a web service via PowerShell. This is what I have so far:-

```
$uri = https://customertest.rm-manifest.com/PosterUpload2/PosterUpload.svc?wsdl
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -credentials $cred
```

I can then get a list of methods and properties with Get-Member, but when I try to call a method I get 400 bad request. Probably because my arguments are not formatted properly.

```
$arg = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1rUpload2_PosterUpload_svc_wsdl.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsRequest
[xml]$response = $proxy.RetrieveActiveSupplyChains($arg)
```

I don't think I need to pass any data to the method in this example but I think it does expect a single object as a parameter.

Should I be able to use the wsdl to generate/format my argument object? If so how do I retrieve the information.

Thanks.